# Fill blank cells from previous columns pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a simple dataframe such as:

```
q_1     q_1_mark    q_2    q_2_mark
TRUE    a           1      c
FALSE   b           2   
TRUE    c           3
```

How could I fill in the blank values of the q_2_mark column, so they matched with q_1_mark? So the steps would be:

1. Look into the column and find the blank values.
2. Look into the previous _mark column and bring across the value for only the blank cells.

I can do brute force copy and paste style formatting, but this loses any cells that contain anything different from the previous column, i.e a --> c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is `df`, Try:

```
df.q_2_mark = df.q_2_mark.combine_first(df.q_1_mark) 

     q_1 q_1_mark  q_2 q_2_mark
0   True        a    1        c
1  False        b    2        b
2   True        c    3        c
```

Answer (score 5):

```
df.q_2_mark.fillna(df.q_1_mark, inplace=True)

df
     q_1 q_1_mark  q_2 q_2_mark
0   True        a    1        c
1  False        b    2        b
2   True        c    3        c
```